Dubious step while solving $8^k+2^k=5$
This question is not about how to solve this. It is a depressed cubic in disguise so applying Cardano's formula would be straightforward.
My question is, someone solved it on YouTube in a different way, and got the correct answer, and there is one step for which I don't understand the rationale or justification. So I am going to post the steps used in the YouTube video. It is probably something very simple that I am missing. Please treat me as if I were not a mathematician but an engineer (which is what I am).
$8^k+2^k=5$, find $k \in \mathbb{R}$
$(2^k)^3+2^k=5$
Let $m=2^k$
$m^3=5-m$
Let $m=a+b \implies m^3=(a+b)^3=a^3+b^3+3ab(a+b)=5-m$
$a^3+b^3+3abm=5-m$
Up to this point, I have no objections. I am a bit puzzled about why he defines $m=a+b$, why he decides to replace only some $m$'s with $a+b$, and why he replaces some of the $a+b$ to $m$, but I don't see anything questionable or that I don't understand what he is doing. But then he says and does this:
"Now let us compare the first two terms to $5$, and the last term to $m$, because they are similar components"
$\bbox[yellow]{a^3+b^3}+\bbox[lime]{3abm}=\bbox[yellow]{5}\bbox[lime]{-m}$
"It follows that:"
$a^3+b^3=5$   and   $3abm=-m$
And I am like, what? It's not like you are equating two complex numbers so $Re$ must equal $Re$ and $Im$ must equal $Im$.
It's not even that you are equating two polynomials of $m$ so the coefficients of each power of $m$ must match. Or is it?
I mean, yeah, it looks like that at first sight. $a^3+b^3+3abm$ looks like a linear polynomial in $m$ and $5-m$ looks like (and in this case is) a linear polynomial in $m$ too.
But it looks to me that that's not the case for the first one. I mean, it's not like $a^3+b^3$ is the independent coefficient ($y$-intercept), independent from $m$. Because $a$, $b$ and $m$ were defined as functions of each other. For example, $a=m-b$, so the first "linear equation in $m$" can be written as:
$(m-b)^3+b^3+3abm$
Where did the "similar component" (whatever that means) go now? Suddenly $(m-b)^3+b^3$ doesn't look as the independent coefficient of a linear polynomial in $m$ anymore. Or does it? I am so confused because it worked!!!
So what is the rationale or justification for doing that? That is my only doubt and question.

What follows is not part of my question anymore.
After that, it's quite trivial. He cancels the $m$'s, finds $a$ and $b$ (after another change of variables), and solves back to $m$ and from there to $k$ using $\log$. A bit tedious but nothing dubious. Here it is in case someone is interested.
$3ab=-1 \implies (3ab)^3=27a^3b^3=(-1)^3=-1$
Let $x=a^3$ and $y=b^3$, then
$x+y=5$ and $27xy=-1$
$27x(5-x)=-1$
$27x^2-135x-1=0$
$x=\frac{135\pm\sqrt{135^2-4\cdot27\cdot(-1)}}{2\cdot27}$
$x_1\approx5.007396$
$x_2\approx-0.007396$
$y_1=5-x_1\approx-0.007396$
$y_2=5-x_2\approx5.007396$
Note that $x_1=y_2$ and $x_2=y_1$; that's due to the nature of the symmetry of the two equations that relate $x $  and  $ y$; so we need to take only one set of solutions since the other set will yield the same results. Let's take $x=x_1$ and $y=y_1$:
$a=\sqrt[3]{x}\approx1.710819$
$b=\sqrt[3]{y}\approx-0.194834$
$m=a+b\approx1.515985$
$m=2^k \implies \log m=k\log 2 \implies k=\frac{\log m}{log 2}\approx0.600255$

suggest you go through the usual derivation of Cardano's solution for $t^3 + p t + q$   maybe write with $p=1$  to match your question https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano's_formula

@WillJagy, that is what I did. $m^3+m-5=0$  is a cubic that is already depressed so applying Cardano's formula is very straightforward. But my question is NOT how to solve this. It is about a step I don't understand in how someone else solved this. All of the above is explained in the 1st 2 sentences of my question.

@GabrielBrown For what it's worth, I agree with you.  If I apply the approach taken in Cardano's formula, I also get equations like $~(r + s) = y, ~3rs = -1, ~y^3 +y - 5 = 0,~$ which leads to $$\left( ~r^3 ~\right)^2 - 5(r^3) - \frac{1}{27} = 0.$$  This result is consistent with what you have indicated was presented in the youtube video.  However, like you, I also can not follow their logic.  The lesson from this is (for the most part), take your math lessons from books and (for example) take youtube videos with a grain of salt.  ...see next comment

@GabrielBrown There may be some analytical explanation for the youtube video's steps.  However, I am simply not seeing it.

@GabrielBrown I think you misunderstood Will Jagy's comment.  They were not saying you could solve the problem using Cardano's method.  I believe they were suggesting that you look at the proof of Cardano's method, as that will make clear why the youtuber did what they did.

@tkf I disagree with your suggesting that Will Jagy's comment was misunderstood.  I think that I and the OP both interpreted Will Jagy's comment as you have.  However, as I indicate in my previous comments, while my application of Cardano's approach leads to a result consistent with the youtube video, that does not explain the step by step analysis taken in the youtube video.  Perhaps I am overlooking something obvious.  However, I also do not understand the youtube video's analysis.

The "It follows that" is misleading if you are not already familiar with the aforementioned proof.  What the youtuber meant was the converse: that is the line below implies the line above.

Basically, if you replace "It follows that" with "It follows that any solution in $a,b$ to the following two equations, will provide a solution to the above equation for any $m$.  In particular if we take $m=a+b$ the LHS becomes $m^3$, so $m$ will satisfy $m^3=5-m$." then the youtuber's solution makes perfect sense.  Because it is a very standard move, they abbreviated this step, to the point where it would not make sense to someone who has not seen it before.

Guys, I asked... treat me like an engineer, not a mathematician :-) When I use Cardano's formula I just plug p and q and get the roots. And the proof is not in the Wikipedia article that Will linked. But, @tfk, I think I am starting  to understand your last comment. It is NOT true that $a^3+b^3+3abm=5−m \implies a^3+b^3=5 $  and  $ 3ab=-1$, but it IS true that $a^3+b^3=5 $  and  $ 3ab=-1 \implies a^3+b^3+3abm=5−m $ for any m, including the case of interest where m=a+b. Correct? Not too sure yet where I go from there though...

@tkf  thank you. I wanted the OP  to derive Cardano's solution, write out the details  in that setting, prove it for himself. That would explain whatever is on  youtube.

@GabrielBrown correct.  So the youtuber then finds numbers $a,b$ that solve the two equations and sets $m=a+b$, to get numbers $a,b,m$ satisfying $$a^3+b^3+3ab(a+b)=5-m.$$ But the left handside here is just $(a+b)^3$ which is just $m^3$.  So they have found a number $m$ which satisfies $m^3=5-m$.

@tfk, thank you, I think I got it now. Why don't you post your explanation as a response to my question instead of a comment? I see that it is very common to have questions with 0 answers but lot of comments including comments that answer the question. I am relatively new here and I don't understand why. In any case, thanks again!!!

The youtuber wanted to solve the equation $m^3=5-m$.  They substituted $m=a+b$.  This step may appear counter-intuitive, but this is in fact the first step in proving Cardano's solution, so quite natural to anyone who has seen that.
They note that if $$a^3+b^3=5, \qquad{\rm and} \qquad3ab=-1\qquad (1)$$
then $$a^3+b^3+3abm=5-m,\qquad(2)$$ for any $m$, so in particular for $m=a+b$.
They then find numbers $a,b$ which satisfy $(1)$ and therefore $(2)$, for any $m$ (hence in particular when $m=a+b$).
Replacing $m$ with $a+b$ in the left hand side of $(2)$ we get: $$a^3+b^3+3abm=a^3+b^3+3ab(a+b)\\=(a+b)^3\\=m^3.$$
Thus the number $m$ they have attained is a solution of $m^3=5-m$.

Lemma, we need this twice:  given real $c,d $ with $c^2 - 4 d \geq 0,$  there are real $a,b$ such that $a+b = c$ and  $ab = d,$  namely
$$  a = \frac{c \pm \sqrt{c^2 - 4d}}{2},  \; \;   b = \frac{c \mp \sqrt{c^2 - 4d}}{2}. $$ Note that we may interchange $a,b$
Next, let $x$   be the real root of $$ x^3 + px + q = 0,$$
in the case $p  > 0$ so there is just one real root.
TO DERIVE CARDANO'S SOLUTION:
Name two new variables $y,z$  such that
$$ y + z = x \; , \; \; \; yz = \frac{-p}{3}  $$
Compare with the Lemma, with real $c=x$ and $d= -p/3$  we do get $c^2 - 4 d >0 .$  We don't write out the expressions from the Lemma just yet. The trick is to push $y,z$ back into the cubic  first.
Using these variables we may now write
$x^3 + px + q$  as (CHECK!!)
$$ y^3 + z^3 + q$$
So we have a new system as in the Lemma,
$$  y^3 + z^3 = -q \; , \; \; y^3 z^3 = \frac{-p^3}{27} $$
So, solve for $y^3, z^3$  as in the lemma, take cube roots   to have expressions for $y,z,$  finally $x$ is their sum.
