$a^3 + a = c$; solve for a. Is Wolfram Alpha right about this?
I saw a maths video on Youtube wherein the author shows how to solve for $a$ in
$$a^3+a=10$$
Essentially his solution method rests on recognising that $10$ can be written as $2^3+2$. From there he demonstrates the existance of some complex solutions, in addition to the real solution: $a=2$.
I wondered if it could be solved for some arbitrary constant $c$.
So I entered this into Wolfram Alhpa, not expecting to get much interesting.
However, I got some really funky results:

I tried implementing the first form in R to see what it does
c <- 10

x <- sqrt(81*c^2 + 12) + 9*c
n1 <- 2^(1/3)
n2 <- x^2/3
n3 <- 2*3^(1/3)

numerator <- n1 * n2 - n3

d1 <- 6^(2/3)
d2 <- x^(1/3)

denominator <- d1 * d2

result <- numerator / denominator

print(result)

It does not print the right result. Maybe I made a coding mistake.
Is Wolfram Alpha confused in this case? Is this legit?

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Depressed_cubic

I put a recent answer on $x^3 + px + q = 0$   with a short derivation https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4987496/dubious-step-while-solving-8k2k-5/4987512#4987512   I did the special case with $p>0$

That said, it would be mildly interesting to see an explicit simplification of the cube root of $\sqrt{8112}+90$ which could be plugged in to the formula to simplify the solution to 2.

It appears $\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{8112}+90} = 2^{1/3} \cdot 3^{1/6} (2 + \sqrt{3})$.

Most likely,
$\text{n2 <- x^2/3}$
is misrendered. With standard operation order you are squaring $x$ and dividing by $3$ when you intended to take the cube root of $x^2$.
Properly, render the exponent in parentheses:
$\text{n2 <- x^(2/3)}$

I can't beleive I missed that.

I can, because I do such things all the time.
